# Pip upgrade pip failing in ansible

Tags: python, pip, ansible, vagrant, virtualbox

I've upgraded my virtualbox to `bento/ubuntu-20.04`
and I'm trying to rebuild the vm. The machine boots OK. I've had to make some changes to the ansible playbook but I'm stuck on the `upgrade pip` task.

```
  - name: upgrade pip
    pip:
      name: pip
      state: latest
      virtualenv_site_packages: yes
      virtualenv: /lc/venv22/
      virtualenv_python: python3.8
```

ansible downloads the latest pip, 21.3.1, finds the installed pip 20.0.2 and successfully uninstalls but fails on installation of the new pip. I get

`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/lc/venv22/bin/pip3", "install", "-U", "pip"]`

and

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '_internal'`

Python 3.8

Vagrant 2.2.19

virtualbox 6.0.10

ansible 5.2.0

If I run `vagrant provision` again I get
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli`

Comment: Is your venv located on a vagrant synced folder ? If this is the case see https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12057. What happens if you issue the pip command manually in your vm ? If you get the same result, this is definitely not related to ansible.